# Prove that $x^n \leq n!$ for all natural numbers $n \geq xe$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $x \geq 0$. I'm trying to prove that $x^n \leq n!$ for all natural numbers $n \geq xe$. Stirling's approximation suggests that this inequality holds; indeed
$$
n! \approx \sqrt{2\pi n} (n / e)^n \geq x^n \quad \text{for all $n \geq xe$,}
$$
but I'm not sure how to make this rigorous. Also, it would be best if this could be proven without needing to use Stirling's approximation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only case of the problem you really need to solve is the extreme case where $n=xe$. Hence, you want to show that:
$$\bigg(\frac{n}{e}\bigg)^n \leqslant n!$$
Can you proceed from here? You could try using induction.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to prove the inequality mentioned in @Haran's answer using induction, but it also follows by writing the Taylor series expansion for $e^n$:
$$
e^n = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{n^k}{k!} \geq \frac{n^n}{n!}.
$$